# Why is there a 'Mixed Content' alert when calling images with a relative path on a https site?

Tags: html, https, path, relative-path, absolute-path

On my subdomain site (https://m.domain.com), I always have to call my images using absolute path (//domain.com/image/img.png). If I use a relative path  (/image/img.png). Chrome will have an error which says that it is a mixed content and http content should not be served over https.

But I don't have this problem on my main site (https://www.domain.com). I can use relative paths without a problem. Why is the difference? Thank you.